# "Request for More information" in approval process

Tags: approval-process

I have faced this scenario multiple times and have done some hack around. I am interested in best design to implement this.

Using SFDC OOB approval process, user can only approve or reject the record. However, If approver want to request for more information from end user, how it can be implemented best way.